# Android - Retrieve and filter data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm here because I want a method which will retrieve data from my firebase and filter the data as I get the incoming event based on device date. Like if the date = 10h30, it give me current event which is 9h00-11h00 and the next event which is 11h00-11h30.

My firebase-firestore data look like this:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? The Firestore documentation on queries should give you a good place to start: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries

Comment: I really don't know how to do this so i tried anything =/

Comment: In that case I would suggest starting from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries. Without more context on what problem you have, it is unlikely we can explain it here better than the Firebase documentation does.